# Recreate Burndown Chart

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create burndown chart in the middle of Sprint.

- We added few more tasks during the iteration, and now the Burndown is not meeting its ideal line. So we want to create the burndown chart again where ideal line is created considering the original estimate of the tasks which are added in middle of an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the chart unless you change the sprint dates or you're looking at doing some custom reporting with SSRS (which is not going to be worth the effort).

Why change it anyway?  It's reflecting exactly what happened during the sprint - you planned your sprint, tasked out the stories and then mid-sprint found some more tasks.  You're unlikely to stick exactly with the ideal trend in any sprint, it's just a guide.  Use it as a data point and try not to repeat it in the next iteration.